# Benefits to limiting file download speed?

Tags: php, download, nginx

I have a file server and wanting to optimize it the best I can, I was thinking of limiting download speed (via PHP) of the file and wondered is there any benefit to this. Yes it may use less RAM, but with more people it could build up; is that correct?

I'm running Nginx with latest PHP.

### Edit

I just checked I can do bandwidth throttling via Nginx, so I may do it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would it use less RAM? If you're streaming the file from disk out the network port, there's virtually no RAM needed at all. If you do this via PHP though, you need to keep a PHP instance running, which takes up some RAM. If you let it go *slowly*, that instance will be running longer. More and more instances will be piling up running at the same time, all using up more and more RAM.

Your best strategy is to handle requests as fast as you possibly can, because then they're gone and you can stop using system resources to handle them. The frequency of your users won't change, the slower you handle those users the longer they'll stick around using up resources.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond what @deceze wrote - figure out what your limiting resource is before you start "optimizing".

Bandwidth throttling will likely tie up more memory/CPU resources on your server (as the processes may be waiting for network I/O). It will do absolutely no good unless you know, for sure, that network bandwidth is the problem (and if it is, your file server is not what you should optimize - you should improve the network).